# Promises, $mdDialog, and order of operations

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I've got an angular app with a login page that's supposed to show a loading dialog while the request is being processed. If the login succeeds on the backend, I've got no problem and I'm whisked away to the content page. Unfortunately, if the login fails, the loading dialog never gets hidden.

Here's the structure of my code:

```
app.controller('loginController', [
  '$scope',
  '$http',
  '$mdDialog',
  function($scope, $http, $mdDialog) {
    var showLoading = function(message) {
      $mdDialog.show({
        templateUrl: '../views/loading.html',
        controller: function($scope) {
          console.log('dialog created');
          $scope.message = message;
        }
      });
    };

    $scope.credentials = {
      username: '',
      password: ''
    };

    $scope.handleLogin = function() {
      showLoading('Logging in...');
      $http.post('/login', $scope.credentials).then(function success() {
        // go to content page
      }, function error(response) {
        console.log('login failed');
      }).then(function() {
        console.log('hide');
        $mdDialog.hide();
      });
    };
  }
]);
```

In my output I see:

```
login failed
hide
dialog created
```

I'm wondering if I'm maybe misunderstanding how promises work or maybe there's something internally in the `$mdDialog` service that is working on a timeout of some sort.

Comment: You should use Angular-loading-bar http://chieffancypants.github.io/angular-loading-bar/ for all `$http` requests to backend.

Comment: Are you expecting that second then() to function as a finally?  If so... change it to a finally(function() {});  See here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q for The Promise API section explaining it.

Comment: @Zach I just tried that too, but it still gets called before the dialog is created and shown

Comment: @nextt1 Thank you for your comment, that's a very nice looking interceptor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you see in output the dialog created only after the login failure. Try to make http request after "show" action is finished:

```
app.controller('loginController', [
'$scope',
'$http',
'$mdDialog',
function($scope, $http, $mdDialog) {
    var showLoading = function(message, onShown) {
        $mdDialog.show({
            templateUrl: '../views/loading.html',
            controller: function($scope) {
                console.log('dialog created');
                $scope.message = message;
            },
            onComplete:onShown
        });
    };

    $scope.credentials = {
        username: '',
        password: ''
    };

    $scope.handleLogin = function() {
        showLoading('Logging in...', function(){
            $http.post('/login', $scope.credentials).then(function success() {
                // go to content page
            }, function error(response) {
                console.log('login failed');
            }).finally(function() {
                console.log('hide');
                $mdDialog.hide();
            });
        });
    };
}
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the then method, you can put three functions.

You must put your "$mdDialog.hide();" in the second function, not the third.
The third function is only used when you fire a long request and you want to indicate the percent of advancement of your request.

Something like this must work :

```
$http.post('/login', $scope.credentials).then(function success() {
        // go to content page
      }, function error(response) {
        console.log('login failed');
        $mdDialog.hide();
      });
```

Comment: The problem is, I'm not using the progress function, I'm using another `.then()` that is called after the post promises resolve. If you look closely at my code, I'm not passing anything for the progress parameter

Comment: Actually, that's not the third function he's wiring up there... he chained a second then() and is setting it in the success function of the second then();.  I would remove the second then and put it in the error response as Oreste Viron indicated.

Comment: I've tried that too and it doesn't work. The `.hide()` is getting called before the dialog is created and shown